# Transfer Values from Object to an Array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Below is my Attempt, I have an object which has array of objects within it, it has a field: 'positionTitle'.

I also have an array of objects which also has a 'positionTitle'

They both have similar data I want all of the values for the positionTitles in my 'individualsData' to go into 'graphData' and be able to now use this new graphData!

I think my attempt is wrong its treating them both as arrays?

Thanks, Dale

```js
graphData = {
  "engagementAreas": [{
    "id": "1",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "forestry",
        "engagements": []
      },
      {
        "name": "houses",
        "engagements": [{
          "name": "engagement1",
          "members": [{
            "position": {
              "id": "3434",
              "positionTitle": "Manager"
            }
          }]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "landscaping",
  "engagements": [{
    "name": "engagement1343",
    "members": [{
      "position": {
        "id": "4545",
        "positionTitle": "Senior Manager"

      }
    }]
  }]
}

IndividualData = [{
  "account": {
    "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF",
    "fullName": "Adnan A. Khan"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
    "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy",
    "positionLevel": "5-Middle Management & Advisers",
    "isPrimary": true,
    "startDate": "2016-10-07",
    "endDate": null
  }]
}, {
  "account": {
    "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO",
    "fullName": "Christine Leong"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "a160X000004nKfhQAE",
    "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
    "positionLevel": "4-Head of Business Unit/Head of Region",
    "isPrimary": true,
    "startDate": "2018-03-05",
    "endDate": null
  }]
}

What I expect to see:  

 NEWgraphData = {
  "engagementAreas": [{
    "id": "1",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "forestry",
        "engagements": []
      },
      {
        "name": "houses",
        "engagements": [{
          "name": "engagement1",
          "members": [{
            "position": {
              "id": "3434",
              "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy" <== from individualsdata
            }
          }]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "landscaping",
  "engagements": [{
    "name": "engagement1343",
    "members": [{
      "position": {
        "id": "4545",
        "positionTitle": "Managing Director" <== also from individuals data

      }
    }]
  }]
}

graphData.engagementAreas.map((el, i) => {
  el.engagementTypes.engagements.members.position.positionTitle = individualsData.positions.positionTitle;
  return el;
})
```

Comment: Please provide the expected result you’d want from the data in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const graphData = {
  "engagementAreas": [{
    "id": "1",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "forestry",
        "engagements": []
      },
      {
        "name": "houses",
        "engagements": [{
          "name": "engagement1",
          "members": [{
            "position": {
              "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
              "positionTitle": "Manager"
            }
          }]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
};

const IndividualData = [{
  "account": {
    "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF",
    "fullName": "Adnan A. Khan"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
    "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy",
    "positionLevel": "5-Middle Management & Advisers",
    "isPrimary": true,
    "startDate": "2016-10-07",
    "endDate": null
  }]
}, {
  "account": {
    "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO",
    "fullName": "Christine Leong"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "a160X000004nKfhQAE",
    "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
    "positionLevel": "4-Head of Business Unit/Head of Region",
    "isPrimary": true,
    "startDate": "2018-03-05",
    "endDate": null
  }]
}, {
  "account": {
    "id": "001b000000Gs91HAAR",
    "fullName": "Cora Ansorg"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "a16b00000022KmhAAE",
    "organizationId": "001b0000006291oAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Strategy Consultant - Financial Services",
    "positionLevel": "5-Middle Management & Advisers",
    "isPrimary": false,
    "startDate": "2012-01-01",
    "endDate": "2015-04-30"
  }]
}]


const allPositions = _.flatten(IndividualData.map(i => i.positions))

const updateMembers = members => members.map(member => {
  const position = allPositions.find(pos => pos.id === member.position.id) || {
    positionTitle: 'untitiled'
  };
  return { ...member,
    position: { ...member.position,
      positionTitle: position.positionTitle
    }
  };
});

const updateEngagements = engagements => (
  engagements.map(engagement => ({
    ...engagement,
    members: updateMembers(engagement.members)
  }))
);

const updateEngagementTypes = (engagementAreas) => ({
  ...engagementAreas,
  engagementTypes: engagementAreas
    .engagementTypes.map(type => ({
      ...type,
      engagements: updateEngagements(type.engagements)
    }))

});

const updatedEngagementAreas = graphData.engagementAreas.map(updateEngagementTypes);

console.log('UpdatedEngagementAreas mapped based on position id', updatedEngagementAreas)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Apparently IndividualData.map(...).flat is not a function

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat
which version of browser are you using